# Does a function for which $f'(x)$ is globally small but $f''(x)$ is globally large exist?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Per title. Does a function for which the magnitude of the first derivative is small (say, $f'(x) < 1$), but the magnitude of the second derivative is large (say, $f''(x) > 10$), exist?

It's easy enough to find functions where this is locally true, e.g. $y = \sin(x)$ around the point $x = \pi/2$, but I'm wondering about the general case. If such functions do not exist, what kind of function allows for the largest possible parameter space such that $f'(x)$ is small but $f''(x)$ is large?

Comment: What do you mean by *small* and *large*?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Let's say $<1$ and $>10$, respectively.

Comment: @Valerin let's take the arbitrary bounds $f'(x) < 1, f''(x) > 10$ -- I'm definitely not thinking infinite values.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem implies

$$f^\prime(x) \gt f^\prime(a) +M(x-a)$$ if

$$f^{\prime \prime}(x) \gt M>0$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Therefore what is asked in the question is not possible if above hypothesis hold.

Comment: What are $M$ and $a$?

Comment: $M=10$ is the value of $f^{\prime \prime}(x) \gt 10$ of the comment of your question.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Assuming the mean value theorem is the one on Wikipedia, I don't see how it leads to the first equation in the answer.